# Test a function which body is inside subscription

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jasmine, rxjs

```
sub: Subject = new Subject();

function funToTest() {
  const localSubscription = this.sub.subscribe(() => {
    this.otherFunctionToBeCalled();
    localSubscription.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

How can I test whether `otherFunctionToBeCalled()` has been called?

```
it('should otherFunctionToBeCalled be called', () => {
  theComponent.funToTest();

  // doesn't work
  expect(theComponent.otherFunctionToBeCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  theComponent.sub.next('something');

  theComponent.funToTest();

  // doesn't work
  expect(theComponent.otherFunctionToBeCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  theComponent.funToTest();

  // doesn't work
  theComponent.sub.subscribe(() => {
    expect(theComponent.otherFunctionToBeCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  spyOn(theComponent.sub, 'subscribe').and.callFake(() => {});

  theComponent.funToTest();
  // doesn't work
  expect(theComponent.otherFunctionToBeCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing you seem to be missing is

```
spyOn(theComponent, 'otherFunctionToBeCalled').and.callThrough();
```

I'd use a `callThrough()` rather than `callFake()`, and of course you need `theComponent.sub.next('something')` to put something through the subscription.

**Demo**

```js
const theComponent = {
  sub: new Rx.Subject(),
  otherFunctionToBeCalled: function() { return 'I need to be called' }
}

const funToTest = function () {
  const localSubscription = theComponent.sub.subscribe(() => {
    theComponent.otherFunctionToBeCalled();
    localSubscription.unsubscribe();
  });
}

describe('some tests', () => {
  it('should otherFunctionToBeCalled be called', () => {
    spyOn(theComponent, 'otherFunctionToBeCalled').and.callThrough();
    funToTest();
    theComponent.sub.next('something')
    expect(theComponent.otherFunctionToBeCalled).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/boot.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```